# QT Creator: no valid kits found

Tags: kde, libraries, qt, sdk

Would you be so kind to help me in trying to add a valid kit to QT Creator? These are the screenshots of kits available options.

Fedora 22 KDE Spin

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, that this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499404/qtcreator-no-valid-kits-found